# Scala: Fold over a list of operations with varied signatures?

Tags: scala, types

I want to write a set of classes that each implement a particular operation, so they take an argument of some type and return something of the same type or a different type. Then, given a list of these operations, fold over an initial value, applying each operation in turn, and supplying the result to the next operation in the list.

For instance, something like this:

```
val program = List[Operation](Add3, ToString, Repeat5)
program.foldLeft(5) ((progress, operation) => operation.apply(progress))
```

So the first operation adds 3, the second turns it into a string, and the last repeats that string 5 times. This would result in:

```
"88888"
```

How do I go about implementing this kind of thing in Scala?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Putting methods of differing signatures in a `List` would be difficult to do in a type-safe way, but you can line them up in a different manner.

```
def add3(i: Int): Float = i + 3.1f
def num2string(f: Float): String = f"$f%.1f"
def repeat5(s: String): String = s * 5

val all = add3 _ andThen num2string andThen repeat5

all(6)  // res0: String = 9.19.19.19.19.1
```

Note that the compiler won't let you put these methods in the wrong order.  That's a nice feature you won't get using a `List` of ops.

---

A chain of `andThen` operations can be built dynamically, at run time, more or less the same as you would to build a `List`.

Start with the argument type. (In your example, `Int`.)

```
val ops0: Int => Int = identity _
```

Now you have an `Int => Int` function and you can add ops, or not, depending on the current conditions.  The type will always be `Int => ??` where ?? is the return type of the last op added to the chain.

Comment: Right, but what if I want the operations to be dynamic? The reason I am trying to put them into a List is that I want to create the sequence of operations as data at runtime. Open to any other approaches!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.Var is discouraged ,but at this time time this is the best I came up with

```
abstract class Operation
  case class Add3() extends Operation with Function[Int, Int] {
    def apply(x: Int) = x + 3
  }

  case class ToString() extends Operation with Function[Int, String] {
    def apply(x: Int) = x.toString
  }

  case class Repeat5() extends Operation with Function[String, String] {
    def apply(s: String) = s * 5
  }

  val lst = List[Operation](Add3(), ToString(), Repeat5())
  var v = "5"
  lst.foreach { op =>
    {
      v = op match {
        case op: Add3     => op.apply(v.toInt).toString
        case op: ToString => op.apply(v.toInt)
        case op: Repeat5  => op.apply(v)
      }
    }
  }

  println(v)
```